# How to detect whether connected to computer

Tags: usb, arduino-micro

I built a keypad that can adjust volume, play, pause, skip tracks, and control the arrow and num keys. It has some backlighting under the keys. I'd like to turn this off when the computer is off. Additionally, whenever the computer is restarted the device must be unplugged and plugged back in or the operating system will not register keypresses. Is there a way I can tell if the computer is on or if the device is connected?[image: The keypad]

Comment: Which arduino are you using?

Comment: Is the device USB connected?  Also,  by “Is there a way I can tell if the computer is on or if the device is connected?”, do you mean a way that you yourself can tell, or the Arduino, or your PC, or some combination?

Comment: It's an arduino micro on the inside and is powered and communicates via microusb port. Also, the preferable solution is that the arduino itself can tell if the computer is on as currently it requires no helper software to be running on the host computer and works the same on windows and osx (haven't tested linux yet).

Comment: Try to look in your bios or OS if there is an option to turn off the USB ports when shut down. Otherwise you will need to do it yourself: If your PC has PS2 ports, you can sense the +5V there and check if it is powered off at shutdown; otherwise you will have to open the PC and find some place which turns on only when the PC is on (e.g. the IDE cables coming from the power supply). Then you will have to setup a usb port powered by that 5V or with a transistor controlled by that voltage. I think that this will solve also the reboot problems (since the board will be initialized again at boot)

Comment: What USB library are you using? LUFA? As to the unplugging, you could try adding some delay inside the setup function.

Comment: @frarugi87, I could configure the the ports to turn off when shutdown but then it is impossible to use the ports to power other devices when the power is off.  Surely I should be able to wire into the the middle two cables and listen for the [ACK](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb3.shtml) packets right?

Comment: @Gerben I am using the keyboard function [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/KeyboardPress) as well as a modified version of [this library](http://stefanjones.ca/blog/arduino-leonardo-remote-multimedia-keys/) for control of media keys and volume.

Comment: @amoose136     What is the colour of the USB port you have the device plugged into, also are you powering down the PC or putting it into sleep?

Comment: @RSM The port is non colored (USB 2.0). The computer completely shuts off usually but I still use other ports to charge things like calculators and phones from time to time.

Comment: @amoose136 Hacking the USB protocol is not a really good idea, at least for me. Too much complicated.. If you can't selectively turn off the USB ports (one of my mother boards had three switches to enable the feature on different usb ports) then I'm afraid that the easiest solution would be to add another USB port powered by the internal IDE connectors...

Comment: I think you can use the function [`USBConnected()`](https://github.com/stefanjones/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp#L628-L633) to see if the host is present/alive.

Comment: @Gerben I would imagine that function should do it but it's not clear to me how to access that function. If I just call `USBConnected();` it will say "function not defined at this scope."